# Groupby and concat other column data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby, concatenation

I have one Dataframe.

 Dataframe1:

```
desc  id  result
A      1    Yes
A      2    No
A      3    Yes
A      4    No
B      1    No
B      2    Yes
C      1    Yes
```

Output:

Dataframe2:

```
id    result
1     A_Yes, B_No, C_Yes
2     A_No, B_Yes
3     A_Yes
4     A_No
5
```

It is simply concat desc and result and then group by.

 How should i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We using [`pandas.Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html)

```
(df.desc+'_'+df.result).groupby(df['id']).apply(','.join).reset_index(name='result')

Out[207]: 
   id            result
0   1  A_Yes,B_No,C_Yes
1   2        A_No,B_Yes
2   3             A_Yes
3   4              A_No
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the `desc` and `result` column and after that use [`pandas.groupby.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

```
df['result'] = df['desc'] + '_' + df['result']
df = df.groupby('id').agg({'result': ', '.join})

print(df)
                result
id                    
1   A_Yes, B_No, C_Yes
2          A_No, B_Yes
3                A_Yes
4                 A_No
```